# How to breakpoint and debug angular templates?

Tags: angular

For example, in React you can put a breakpoint in your view/template and check what is going on.

Edit: Let's say I want to see what is going on here:

```
<h2>{{hero.name | uppercase}} Details</h2>
<div><span>id: </span>{{hero.id}}</div>
<div>
  <label>name:
    <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name">
  </label>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/angular/kopjlplrpanj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fheroes%2Fheroes.component.html

I want to inspect the variables in the scope of this template. See their values.

Comment: Can you give us an example of what you're trying to debug?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken debugging templates will come with new render engine `"Ivy"` and at this moment you can only try to debug this variables in `*.ts` file

Comment: debugging is done on the typescript file. Just go to your chrome browser, press f12, go to sources tab, press crt + P and open (your-file-name).ts file and add debugger.

Comment: Html/Template debugging is not possible in angular. You can debug only in .ts file.

Comment: Yes, I need only to debug the template, hence the question. Typescript files are straightforward to debug.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Someone can say that debugging templates will come with Ivy but I would say that we can also easy debug current View Engine.

For example, here are some options I would use:

1) Angular generates ngFactory for each component which can be found by path `ng://ModuleName/ComponentName.ngfactory.js`.

Each factory contains two methods `updateDirectives` and `updateRenderer` where you can debug your variables.

[image]

2) Make some mistake in template

```
<h2>{{herox.name | uppercase}} Details</h2>
         ^^^^
```

Now you can find the target place in your console

[image]

3) Put the following code at the beginning of your template

```
<ng-container *ngIf="1; let x='ngIf; debugger'">{{x}}
```

And you will automatically moved to updating template code

[image]

For more info see

- [**Catch Angular template errors like a pro or how I create Angular Demo**](https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/catch-angular-template-errors-like-a-pro-or-how-i-create-angular-demo-e98694977911)

### Update:

I agree that it's hard to understand the generated code so that in simple cases you do not need that and you can just look at the value through printing it somewhere, i.e:

```
{{myVar}}
```

or

```
<div [attr.debug-var]="someVar">
```

### Update 2

```
{{ this.constructor.__proto__.constructor('', 'debugger')() }}
```

https://twitter.com/yurzui/status/1179436748826394626

Comment: Thanks, I got it, but that code looks way different than the template in the source code and I find it very hard to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below steps:

1. Open Developer Console
2. Goto: Sources tab
3. Goto Sub tab: Page
4. You generally have your angular project files in `webpack://` or `ng://` or such related menuItem folder, find your Angular project files.
5. Then, find your Template file
6. Attach a *Breakpoint* on the line on which you want to the see data, and
7. Reload your page Or Execute that part of the code or Execute the Event for that code (If that part of the code runs on a Button click or mouse hover, Go ahead and click the button or hover mouse)
8. You will generally see your Data in the `_co` field of the *Breakpoint Scope*

[image]